# nestedSortable on codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I do sorting function with codeigniter for pages with "nestedSortable".. When i click submit button it doesnt find " {sortable: cSortable}"

my code example:
in views

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post('<?php echo site_url('admin/pages/order_ajax'); ?>', {}, function(data) {
        $('#orderResult').html(data);

    });

    $('#save').click(function() {
        oSortable = $('.sortable').nestedSortable('toArray');
        $.post('<?php echo site_url('admin/pages/order_ajax'); ?>', {sortable: cSortable}, function(data) {
            $('#orderResult').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

in model file

```
 public function save_order($pages) {
    if (count($pages)) {
        foreach ($pages as $order => $page) {
            dump($page);
            if ($page['item_id'] != '') {
                $data = array('parent_id' => (int) $page['parent_id'], 'order' => $order);
                $this->db->set($data)->where($this->_primary_key, $page['item_id'])->update($this->_table_name);
                echo '<pre>' . $this->db->last_query() . '</pre>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in the controller file

```
  public function order_ajax() {

        // save order from ajax call
        if (isset($_POST['sortable'])) {
            $this->page_m->save_order($_POST['sortable']);
        }
    //fetch all pages

    $this->data['pages'] = $this->page_m->get_nested();
    //fetch view

    $this->load->view('admin/pages/order_ajax', $this->data);
}
```

I see this error http://i57.tinypic.com/2uj6wpd.jpg

another error:

```
  <?php
echo get_ol($pages);

function get_ol($array, $child = FALSE) {
    $str = '';
if (count($array)) {
    $str .= $child == FALSE ? '<ol class="sortable">' : '<ol>';

    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $str .= '<li id="list_' . $item['id'] . '">';
        $str .= '<div>' . $item['title'] . '</div>';

        //do we have childrens ?
        if (isset($item['children']) && count($item['children'])) {
            $str .= get_ol($item['children'], TRUE);
        }

        $str .= '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    $str .= '</ol>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    return $str;
}
```

?>
so i dont get it shows me on line 10 and 11 that could't find name and title

"TypeError: parentItem is null

pid = parentItem[2];"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a type, wrong variable name.  Should cSortable actually be oSortable?

Comment: Jap its worked to me but another error i get when i put created page inside other page top.. http://i60.tinypic.com/v7cah3.jpg